Add Functionality to ArcGIS Online Web Maps
I have created a Web Map, which is hosted on ArcGIS Online. This Web Map is the source for a map in another non-ESRI Application.
I was wondering if it is possible to tweak the functionality of the web map to include a few things that the Web Application / Experience Builder have. For example, in the Search Widget a user can limit the address search to a specific country. Is there a way to add these types of functions to an ESRI Web Map.
